# Format string when translating from Excel to xml

Tags: excel, xml, documentation

I add headers and footers to my Excel file. Rename the file to zip format and pull out the first sheet(xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml), then I see this line `<oddHeader>&C&"Britannic Bold,bold italics"&U&KFF0000"mytext"</oddHeader>`
Where can I find documentation on how this string is formed, what parameters are allowed, etc?

Answer (score 0):

[Microsoft has documentation for the XML spreadsheet format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.spreadsheet?view=openxml-2.8.1)

For your specific question, the [OddHeader class is documented here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.spreadsheet.oddheader?view=openxml-2.8.1)